# discord.js throws TOKEN_INVALID when I use the token I got from browser in discord.com

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My final goal : I would like to get every single channels in every single guilds I belong to.

As a first step, created simple program that I identify that I am logged in as myself.

I first found my token via [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEgFvgg7ZPI)

In a nutshell the video instructs to get the token via

Chrome -> discord.com -> F12 -> Application -> Local Storage -> filter "token" -> click "Toggle device toolbar" -> voila

Threw it in .env as variable `TOKEN=...` and my index.js is implemented as followings

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  ]
});

client.on('ready', ()=> {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

However, when I run `node index.js` I receive following errors

```
D:\SourceTree\discord.js\00_get_server_channel_list\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:129
    const invalidToken = new Error(WSCodes[4004]);
                         ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

Is the token found in the video wrong?
Or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a discord bot
The token you get from that video is your user token, not your bots token.
To get your bots token go to https://discord.com/developers/applications
Go to your Bots Application > Bot Tab on the left > Reset Token > Copy Token

If you dont already have an application press New Application, Name it > Bot tab on the left > Build  A Bot > Reset Token > Copy Token

https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-token/
Read Through this if ur having trouble

Comment: Fundamental question. Does discord.js only work with bots? I really do not plan on making discord bot that reacts to certain inputs etc, but I want to make analysis tool for my own account. Is discord bot able to analyze my account? (analyze in the sense of my goal written at the beginning)

Comment: I believe the script you wrote would only work with discord bots

Comment: I see... too bad, would you have any pointer to right direction with my purpose / goal?

Comment: I have not seen anything regarding your goal but I may be wrong and it could be totally possible

Comment: This token is not valid for bots. Its your discord account token.